# What's wrong with the code?

Tags: parametric-functions

The following code doesn´t fill the base of the picture. ¿Why?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All];
fy[x_] := Sqrt[1 - (x^2/4)];
latas = ParametricPlot3D[{t, fy[t], s}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, .5}];
latai = ParametricPlot3D[{t, -fy[t], s}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, .5}];
latab = ParametricPlot3D[{t, s, 0}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, -fy[t], fy[t]}];
Show[{latai, latas, latab}]
```

Comment: Please post your code in copyable format so that we can help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All];
fy[x_] := Sqrt[1 - (x^2/4)];
latas = ParametricPlot3D[{t, fy[t], s}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, .5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];
latai = ParametricPlot3D[{t, -fy[t], s}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, .5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];
latab = ParametricPlot3D[{t, s, 0}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, -fy[t], fy[t]}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];
Show[{latai, latas, latab}]
```